# How To Display Date Picker View Without Days in Objective-C

Tags: xcode, date, uipickerview, uidatepicker

Is it possible to exclude the days in the date picker view? if yes, how can I do it? I don't want to create an array of years if there's a way for me to just exclude the days in the date picker. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with UIDatePicker. I recommend subclassing [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) and implementing it on your own.